# MySQL package for python 3.7

Tags: mysql, python-3.7

I am in the need of saving data into a MySQL database, my problem is I can't find the package...

Solution explored:

- Oracle website: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
- Trying to install MySQLdb from Pycharm it said non existing.

So if anyone has an alternative to it for python 3.7, or knows how to get the connector for version 3.7 I would be happy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two ways to install MySQL connector. The second way is preferred.

### 1. [MySQL Installer](https://www.mysql.com/downloads/)

This is Oracle's product installer. The problem is that it is outdated. It is only aware of Python version 3.6, and nothing newer. To install for a newer version of Python, use option 2.

### 2. Python package manager, `pip`

The Python package manager comes with Python, called [`pip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_pip.asp). It downloads the package from the [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) repository and installs it in an automatic location based on what version of Python (or what [virtual copy](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)) you use to install it. The package that you want is `mysql-connector-python`. In fact, the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/installation.html) says this is the recommended method for installing the MySQL Connector.

For example, on Windows, open up the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) by searching in the Start Menu. Navigate to the directory where `pip` is installed. Or make sure that `pip`'s directory is included in the $PATH variable (which you can edit by searching for "PATH" in the Start Menu).

The command prompt will show you this:

```
PS C:\Users\Ryan>
```

except instead of my username, it'll show your username, or the path you navigated to after you found `pip`, like "C:\blah\blah". Then use this command...

Input:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

It downloads and installs it.

Results:

```
PS C:\Users\Ryan> pip install mysql-connector-python
Collecting mysql-connector-python
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/65/3fc902c0f7635912800c6b935313b99b9d4426419ef7ba04f76231b24923/mysql_connector_python-8.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (300kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 307kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting protobuf>=3.0.0 (from mysql-connector-python)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/78/a7f1ce761e2c738e209857175cd4f90a8562d1bde32868a8cd5290d58926/protobuf-3.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (390kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 399kB 1.8MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.0.0->mysql-connector-python) (40.4.3)
Collecting six>=1.9 (from protobuf>=3.0.0->mysql-connector-python)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, protobuf, mysql-connector-python
Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.12 protobuf-3.6.1 six-1.11.0
```

Afterward, you can make sure it is installed by displaying all packages that have been installed by you (not including standard libraries, which come with Python):

Input:

```
PS C:\Users\Ryan> pip list
```

Results:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
mysql-connector-python 8.0.12
pip                    18.0
protobuf               3.6.1
setuptools             40.4.3
six                    1.11.0
```

To check if you installed it to the right version of Python, use `pip -V`. To make sure you installed it to the right copy (virtual or original), look at the file path where the package was installed:

```
PS C:\Users\Ryan> pip -V
```

Results:

```
pip 18.0 from c:\users\ryan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

For example, in my system, it shows `python37` in the folder path, so it installed it to the original Python 3.7.0 installation I have, instead of an older version or virtual environment (`conda` or `virtualenv`, etc).

To check the version using the Python executable, instead of `pip`:

```
PS C:\Users\Ryan> py -V
Python 3.7.0
```

If you need to install it to an older or newer Python version than the default installation, insert the version number as an option (aka. "switch") in the command, using `-`. For example, to select version 3.6:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install mysql-connector-python
```

The `-` works on both Windows and Unix-like OSs.

Answer (score 11):

`mysqlclient` supports `python3.7` officially, you can find it here :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

1)you can download , [PyMySQL 0.9.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) 
2)extract & copy the folder `pymysql` into the python `Lib` folder
3)and for connection you can do like this(make a file for example `freeman.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='freemanDB')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

print(cur.description)
print()

for row in cur:
    print(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: you have to install this driver first : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Comment: The drivers only go up to version 3.6 I have version 3.7

Comment: check this out : https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/142

Comment: This is not an answer. If a user *needs* to use the official MySQL package, this does not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

This command on cmd will solve the problem. Run cmd as administrator if in any case you face problem.

Answer (score -2):

You must install flask_mysqldb package in order to use MySQL

```
pip install flask_mysqldb
```

To use it:

```
from project import app

from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

Config MySQL:

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'

app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'

app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'yourpassword'

app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'mydbfile'

app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'MyCursor'
```