# Packages copy pasted does not appear in the pip list or freeze output?

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

I am using Python 3.7.1 in a virtual environment where I have manually added(copy pasted the *pymysql* folder after extracting it) [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/#files) to the myproject/lib/python3.7/site-packages (myproject being the virtual environment).

Now, I am able to `import pymysql` but `pip list` or `pip freeze` does not show it's installed. Is there a way I can make `pip list/freeze` list it?

Comment: Just curious to know, you preferred to copy the pymysql folder instead of doing a `pip` installation? I tested this on my computer and I did `pip install pymysql` , which lists `PyMySql=0.9.2` for `pip freeze` on Win 7, Python 3.7.

Comment: Referred to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51468110/1977152

Comment: The accepted answer for that SO question wants you to download version 0.9.2 which is also available via `pip` (as in my previous comment). The other answers too recommend installing with `pip`.

Comment: You did copy the source code, but not the package metadata (`egg-info`/`dist-info`). Without it, `pip` won't be able to recognize the package. However, it's easier (and safer) to reinstall the package properly.